# Version conflict for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational when upgrading to ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

After migrating my project from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to 5.0 I have encountered this problem:

> Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.
>
> Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 5.0.0 directly to project Alpha.Web.App to resolve this issue.
>
> Alpha.Web.App ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 5.0.0 ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.0 ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 5.0.0)
>
> Alpha.Web.App ->
> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 3.2.4 ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 3.1.8 && <
> 5.0.0).
>
> E:\Projects\Alpha\Alpha.Web.App\Alpha.Web.App.csproj  1

How can I solve it?

**Alpha.Web.App.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>XXXXXXuser secret idXXXXXXXX</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
          <!-- ...-->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
          <!-- ...-->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
          <!-- ...-->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="migrations.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.28" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.0" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="3.3.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>


    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.6.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic.Core" Version="1.2.5" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Alpha.DataAccess\Alpha.DataAccess.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Alpha.Infrastructure\Alpha.Infrastructure.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Alpha.LoggerService\Alpha.LoggerService.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Alpha.Models\Alpha.Models.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Alpha.Services\Alpha.Services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
   <!-- ...-->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
   <!-- ...-->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Have you upgraded your Entity Framework Core to latest one?

Comment: Yes, I did it. You can see it.
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />

Comment: I have removed Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and now it works well.
At this moment there is no compatible Pomelo package for .net5.0

Comment: Post it as an answer, people are testing it these days and they might come onto this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` and now it works well.
At this moment there is no compatible Pomelo package for .NET 5:

https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#schedule-and-roadmap

Answer (score 0):

Just install a newer compatible Pomelo package.

`Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (v5.0.0)` is actually compatible with the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (v5.0.x)`